# Using NSFileManager to return if directory does not exit

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I have the following code that returns an `NSArray` of the names of files in a given directory. This works fine when the directory exists but what I would like to know is how I can first check whether or not the directory at *directoryPath* actually exists.

```
NSString *directoryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSFileManager` class has a built in method, which is used to check if a file exists at a path or not.

The function goes like this :

```
[fileManagerObject fileExistsAtPath : @"PUT_YOUR_FILE_PATH_HERE" isDirectory : YES]; //If its a file that you're looking to check then put isDirectory as NO, but if its a folder then enter YES as the parameter
```

Here's how you would typically use it in your code :

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"FILE_PATH_HERE" isDirectory:NO] == YES)
{
   //Yes. The file exists, continue with your operation.
}
else
{
   //No. The file doesn't exist.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NSFileManager's fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory: method.

Answer (score 1):

```
fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:
```

Return Value
YES if a file at the specified path exists or NO if the file’s does not exist or its existence could not be determined.

[Apple Documentation for NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added the code from Sanjeet and it seems to work and so I am not sure  what your comment means.

Comment: u said u want to check if directory exists or not, and here he is checking for file.

Answer (score 1):

Following NSFileManger API can give the desired results:

[fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a)

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *pathToDocumentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    BOOL isDir;
    NSString *subfolder = [pathToDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileExistsAtPath:YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:subfolder isDirectory:&isDir]) {

//No directory exist
         [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:subfolder withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
else{
//directory exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks - appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
NSString *directoryPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
BOOL isDirectory;
BOOL isExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath isDirectory:&isDirectory];
if (isExists) {
    /* file exists */
    if (isDirectory) {
        /* file is a directory */

    }
 }
```